# Removing elements of array causes multiple re-renders

Tags: javascript, lodash, mobx

I have a MobX observable array, and I want to remove multiple elements with lodash's [**remove**](https://lodash.com/docs#remove). This causes a re-render for every element in the array.

```
const array = observable([1,2,3,4,5,1]);

const App = observer(() => {
  console.log('Rendering...');
  return (
    <div>
      { array.map(e => <div> {e} </div>)}
    </div>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

If I try to remove every occurrence of `1`, `Rendering...` is logged once for every element:

```
_.remove(array, num => num === 1);
> "Rendering..."
> "Rendering..."
> "Rendering..."
> "Rendering..."
> "Rendering..."
> "Rendering..."
```

How can I make it so it just re-renders once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API to MobX looks just like vanilla JavaScript, but every alteration of the observable array causes a synchronous update of all observers. One way to mitigate this is to put the code in a [**runInAction**](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html#runinaction):

```
runInAction(() => _.remove(array, num => num === 1));
> "Rendering..."
```